# SQL Server: Lead/Lag analytic function across groups (and not within groups)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, lag, sliding-window, lead

Sorry for the long post, but I have provided copy & paste sample data and a possible solution approach below. The relevant part of the *question* is in the upper part of the post (above the horizontal rule).

I have the following table

```
 Dt          customer_id  buy_time     money_spent
 -------------------------------------------------
 2000-01-04  100          11:00:00.00  2
 2000-01-05  100          16:00:00.00  1
 2000-01-10  100          13:00:00.00  4
 2000-01-10  100          14:00:00.00  3
 2000-01-04  200          09:00:00.00  10
 2000-01-06  200          10:00:00.00  11
 2000-01-06  200          11:00:00.00  5
 2000-01-10  200          08:00:00.00  20
```

and want a query to get this result set

```
 Dt          Dt_next     customer_id  buy_time     money_spent
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 2000-01-04  2000-01-05  100          11:00:00.00  2
 2000-01-05  2000-01-10  100          16:00:00.00  1
 2000-01-10  NULL        100          13:00:00.00  4
 2000-01-10  NULL        100          14:00:00.00  3
 2000-01-04  2000-01-06  200          09:00:00.00  10
 2000-01-06  2000-01-10  200          10:00:00.00  11
 2000-01-06  2000-01-10  200          11:00:00.00  5
 2000-01-10  NULL        200          08:00:00.00  20
```

That is: I want for each costumer (`customer_id`) and each day (`Dt`) the next day the same customer has visited (`Dt_next`).

I have already one query that gives the latter result set (data and query enclosed below the horizontal rule). However, it involves a `left outer join` and two `dense_rank` aggregate functions. This approach seems a bit clumsy to me and I think that there should be a better solution. **Any pointers to alternative solutions highly appreciated! Thank you!**

BTW: I am using SQL Server 11 and the table has >>1m entries.

---

My query:

```
 select
   customer_table.Dt
   ,customer_table_lead.Dt as Dt_next
   ,customer_table.customer_id
   ,customer_table.buy_time
   ,customer_table.money_spent
 from
 (
   select 
     #customer_data.*
     ,dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by customer_id asc, Dt asc) as Dt_int
   from #customer_data
 ) as customer_table
 left outer join
 (
   select distinct
     #customer_data.Dt
     ,#customer_data.customer_id
     ,dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by customer_id asc, Dt asc)-1 as Dt_int
   from #customer_data
 ) as customer_table_lead
 on
 (
   customer_table.Dt_int=customer_table_lead.Dt_int
   and customer_table.customer_id=customer_table_lead.customer_id
 )
```

Sample data:

```
 create table #customer_data (
   Dt date not null,
   customer_id int not null,
   buy_time time(2) not null,
   money_spent float not null
 );

 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-04',100,'11:00:00',2);
 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-05',100,'16:00:00',1);
 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-10',100,'13:00:00',4);
 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-10',100,'14:00:00',3);

 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-04',200,'09:00:00',10);
 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-06',200,'10:00:00',11);
 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-06',200,'11:00:00',5);
 insert into #customer_data values ('2000-01-10',200,'08:00:00',20);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select cd.Dt
    , t.Dt_next
    , cd.customer_id
    , cd.buy_time
    , cd.money_spent
from (
    select Dt
        , LEAD(Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY Dt) AS Dt_next
        , customer_id
    from (
        select distinct Dt, customer_id
        from #customer_data
    ) t
) t
inner join #customer_data cd on t.customer_id = cd.customer_id and t.Dt = cd.Dt
```

Why field `money_spent` has float type? You may have problems with calculations. Convert it to decimal type.

Comment: Just checked it. Works and the query is much shorter! I will also check the performance with the larger table. Thanks for the hint with the float type (this was just the first type that came to my mind when creating the sample data - the actual table is different from the sample data provided here).

Comment: Found this post by a similar requirement and PARTITION BY is the answer in my scenario. Thanks too :)