# Before and after state transitions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a df

```
   uid       timestamp               event
   34900     2015-01-01 00:00:10     5
   90100     2015-01-07 00:00:00     4
   90100     2015-03-02 00:00:00     9
   34900     2015-01-03 00:00:00     5
   34900     2015-01-01 00:40:00     6
   34900     2015-01-01 00:00:01     2
   90100     2015-03-01 00:07:00     5
   34900     2015-01-04 00:00:09     8
   34900     2015-01-07 00:00:10     2
   90100     2015-01-01 20:00:00     1
```

It has events (1-9) occurring on some unique ids (34900,90100,..) timestamped as datetime.

I am trying to find what happens before and after an event (event=5) occurs on each unique id. My thinking is to subset the df into each unique and retain the adjacent event for each 5 event that happens.

So I will like to know how to retrieve the following dataframes below from the df above

```
uid=34900

   timestamp               before      after
   2015-01-01 00:00:10     2           6
   2015-01-03 00:00:00     6           8
```

uid=90100

```
   timestamp               before      after
   2015-03-01 00:07:00     4           9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Sparrower suggestion, I sorted the data and used the following to obtain the desired outputs.

```
df['before'] = df.groupby(['uid'])['event'].shift(1)
df['after']  = df.groupby(['uid'])['event'].shift(-1)
df1 = df[df['event']==5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just asked the same question yesterday, but for SQL. I was informed about the lead/lag functions. You can find my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500367/sql-project-state-pipeline-query).

Once I knew about lead and lag, it was easy to further my research on the matter. It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664877/pandas-equivalent-of-oracle-lead-lag-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question contains the solution you are looking for in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the code I used based on your suggestion above.